# React-Native Error + Bug in Ruby Interpreter: Failed to install CocoaPods dependencies for iOS project, which is required by this template

Tags: ruby, react-native

I am very new to Apple and app programming so please forgive me if I am not asking my questions in the perfect "format" that you might be expecting...

I bought my MacBook Air running on M1 chip just few days ago and would like to program with Xcode and React Native. As I do the common command "npx react-native init AwesomeProject" I got into the error which I saw quite some other people also run into:

```
error Error: Failed to install CocoaPods dependencies for iOS project, which is required by this template.
```

I tried all of the suggestions available on other posts (assuming I am understanding the remedies correctly and making the changes accordingly) but none seem to work for me.

I tried also the default suggested solution which is:

```
Please try again manually: "cd ./AwesomeProject/ios && pod install".
```

And I seem to get something different from others, which is:

> Analyzing dependencies Fetching podspec for `DoubleConversion` from
> `../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/DoubleConversion.podspec`
> Fetching podspec for `RCT-Folly` from
> `../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/RCT-Folly.podspec`
> Fetching podspec for `glog` from
> `../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/glog.podspec`
> /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.1/lib/ffi/library.rb:275: [BUG]
> Bus Error at 0x0000000102a08000 ruby 2.6.3p62 (2019-04-16 revision
> 67580) [universal.arm64e-darwin20]

and then

> You may have encountered a bug in the Ruby interpreter or extension
> libraries.

Is it something to do with my Ruby interpreter? If yes, what are the commands I could use to solve the issue???

Comment: Try disable flipper. Remove `use_flipper!()` in `ios/Podfile`. After that run `pod install` in ios folder your project.

Comment: are you trying to run any template project ?

Comment: @PavanTank I am just trying to set up Xcode etc. to write React Native for iOS. And I bumped into this error before I am even able to initialise my first test app.

Comment: @PavanTank but I have tried React Native with Android Studio on my Windows desktop before though.

Comment: @VasylNahuliak Hi! Just tried, still the same Ruby bug...

Answer (score 13):

https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/10349#issuecomment-849468291

```
brew install cocoapods
sudo arch -x86_64 gem install ffi
arch -x86_64 pod install
```

Comment: I am not sure if its a new problem, or problem not solved. After I tried your three commands, I can run the init command without problems it seems. however, as I cd into the directory and run "npx react-native start" as in the React Native website, the terminal just gives no output and I was prompt to choose to reload the app or to open developer menu. whichever option I choose, I will be greeted with "No apps connected". why is that??

Comment: I guess you need create a new question with details steps. Thank you

Comment: created the new question... should I just reinstall Xcode or something as what I have been doing seems to create more problems than it solved... Pandora's box...

Comment: I'm on an m1 macbook for development and the key to solving this for myself was the brew command to install cocoapods. What I believe happened was it updated the current version I had. Then running "arch -x86_64 pod install". I had tried this so many different ways, but this was the solution that finally worked for me.

Comment: Ditto here - running just `brew install cocoapods` was sufficient on a new M1 Max MBP - it updated both `ruby` and `cocoapods` with specifically arm64 & monterey versions

Comment: You can see the React Native docs mention some of these commands in the cocoapods section (under the section on M1 macs) on the beta version of the [setup environment guide](https://reactnative.dev/docs/next/environment-setup), where they explain what the commands do.

Comment: Should I run the brew install command if my cocoapods wasn't installed through homebrew? (I had installed cocoapods using what React Native listed in their setup environment guide: `sudo gem install cocoapods`)

Comment: Update: I just uninstalled my cocoapods installation and then installed with homebrew, like [mentioned here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/33017#issuecomment-1044059962). Then I just ran `pod install` and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, need to restart my terminal before execute pod install. Monterey + M1.

Answer (score 0):

The top answer doesn't work for me on my MBP M1 so I fixed the issue this way :

1. Make sure you have opened **project.xcworkspace** and not the **project.xcodeproj**
2. Open the workspace file with xcode with clicking on it then go to **File -> Workspace Settings ... -> Build System -> Legacy Build System**
3. Select the project file then the Target then go to Build Settings Tab and Search Paths

[image]

4. Double click on Library Search Paths Debug and move the $(inherited) to the bottom of the list

[image]

5. Do the same for the Release .

[image]

Then Build Again and you're good to go .

If you still get any errors run these commands in the ios folder of the react native project and do the above steps again and it will build successfully.

`rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/`

`pod deintegrate`

`pod install`

Answer (score 0):

If you are facing this issue in Mac Big Sur, reinstalling CommandLineTools can fix this issue.

```
sudo rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools

xcode-select --install
```