# React Native Command "npx react-native start" does not work

Tags: ruby, react-native, apple-m1

I have bought a new MacBook Air with M1 chip a few days ago and am just trying to set up my react native and Xcode etc. running for writing iOS app.

I have had some issues with "npx react-native init AwesomeProject" previously but hopefully it has been solved. [React-Native Error + Bug in Ruby Interpreter: Failed to install CocoaPods dependencies for iOS project, which is required by this template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68044863/react-native-error-bug-in-ruby-interpreter-failed-to-install-cocoapods-depend)

I assume the init was successful because I got the following run instructions in color:

```
  Run instructions for Android:
    • Have an Android emulator running (quickest way to get started), or a device connected.
    • cd "/Users/boscotsin/Documents/react/test4" && npx react-native run-android
  
  Run instructions for iOS:
    • cd "/Users/boscotsin/Documents/react/test4" && npx react-native run-ios
    - or -
    • Open test4/ios/test4.xcworkspace in Xcode or run "xed -b ios"
    • Hit the Run button
    
  Run instructions for macOS:
    • See https://aka.ms/ReactNativeGuideMacOS for the latest up-to-date instructions.
```

I then proceed to the second step according to React Native document which is to cd into the directory and then run "npx react-native start" but then it won't work. I am given two options:

```
To reload the app press "r"
To open developer menu press "d"
```

And whichever option I choose it will say no apps connected and I will be greeted with either of these:

```
warn No apps connected. Sending "reload" to all React Native apps failed. Make sure your app is running in the simulator or on a phone connected via USB.
info Reloading app...
warn No apps connected. Sending "devMenu" to all React Native apps failed. Make sure your app is running in the simulator or on a phone connected via USB.
info Opening developer menu...
```

I also try to run "npx react-native run-ios" directly and it will also say the build is unsuccessful...

May I know what is wrong here?

Or should I just reinstall Xcode or some other things once and for all???